# Custom class Array in postgres implementation in java using UseerType

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, java-8

I have custom type in Postgres

```
CREATE TYPE BusinessUnit AS
(
  id BIGINT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  pct_source_id BIGINT
);
```

I am using it as `private BusinessUnit[] businessUnits` in my entity class

Business Unit class is :

```
public class BusinessUnit extends BaseStaticData implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    private Long pctSourceId;
}
```

but I am getting `businessUnits` as null

How can I achive this

Comment: what happens when you use a `List`?

Comment: Do you use only JDBC or Hibernate or another ORM based framework?

Comment: I am suing Hibernate

Comment: Suing Hibernate sounds a bit harsh.